# async await not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am new to JavasSript's `async`, `await` and `promise` features.

What I am doing is,

```
async function sendTextMessage(text) {
    console.log("----1----");
    var messageData = {
        message: {
            text: text
        }
    };
   await callSendAPI(messageData);
}

async function sendImageMessage(imageUrl) {
    console.log("----2----");
    var messageData = {
        message: {
            url: imageUrl
        }
    };
  await callSendAPI(messageData);
}

async function sendQuickReply(replies) {
    console.log("----3----");
    var messageData = {
        message: {
            text: text,
            quick_replies: replies
        }
    };
   await callSendAPI(messageData);
}
async function callSendAPI(messageData) {
    await request({
        uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {
            access_token: config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: messageData

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
            var messageId = body.message_id;

            if (messageId) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s",
                    messageId, recipientId);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s",
                    recipientId);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
        }
    });
}
```

I am calling this functions in one switch case like,

```
async function send(){
     await sendTextMessage(text);
     await sendImageMessage(img);
     await sendQuickReply(replies)  
}
send()
```

But while response shows`sendImageMessage()` last because this function may be not getting ready when I am sending `imageUrl` to generate a response.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle of your problem, it helps

Comment: If you are new, learn about asynchronous programming concepts like `callbacks`, `promises`, `async`, `await` in that order. Otherwise, you might end up confused.

Comment: what is that request function call in `callSendAPI` function, can you describe it.

Comment: @PraveenSoni Request function will generate the payload based on the data it get from the three functions and will send it to specific facebook account.

Comment: @PraveenSoni in facebook messenger i am getting image at last while i want image in between other two response

Comment: is `request` fn is made by you, or some library functionality ?
can you post that too

Comment: @PraveenSoni its just formatted function made by me. but the actual reason is the image response is generated at last

Comment: didn't get you. is issue is due to that request function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171383/discussion-between-nikhil-savaliya-and-praveen-soni).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note this answer was written against [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50423873/1) and not later edits made by the OP.

---

An `async` function is asynchronous. Other functions will not wait for it.

So you call `sendTextMessage` which calls `callSendAPI` and then the rest of the program carries on.

`callSendAPI` runs asynchronously. It calls `request` and waits for the promise returned by `request` to be resolved. When it has resolved, `callSendAPI` picks up the return value of `request` (well, it would if you captured the return value) and then continues with the next line (only there isn't a next line).

---

`async` / `await` do not make asynchronous code synchronous. They just make it look like it in **inside** the function declared as `async` which, itself, becomes asynchronous.

---

You could put your three function calls in an `async` function of their own, make sure each one returns a Promise, and then call each of those three with `await`.

---

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: @Sven - The OP has significantly altered their code since I answered the question.

Comment: Ah that explains it, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

I hope that all you want todo is process some operations in strict order.

This is why async and await in ES6 exists.

So by example it may be like this do A then do B then do C or A > B > C

As you can see the last method do3 has only 500 ms delay but it is executed as last and not as first one. 
Without async and await operators it would be executed as first function and this is default behavior of JavaScript execution. Broser will execute sync code as first and async after. But not with async and await anymore :)

You should also know that if you prefix string, number of function with await then  the will be transformed into promise automatically.

The console will print :

'juraj1' 
'juraj2' 
'juraj3'

here is simple example :

```
function do1() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          return setTimeout(() => resolve("juraj1"), 3000);
   });
 }
function do2() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
            return setTimeout(() => resolve("juraj2"), 2000);
  });
 }

function do3() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
             return setTimeout(() => resolve("juraj3"), 500);
  });
}

async function ForceAsynTOBeSync() {
    const a = await do1();

    console.log(a);

    const b = await do2();

    console.log(b);

    const c = await do3();

    console.log(c);
  }

  ForceAsynTOBeSync();
```

Comment: the problem is in request

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the API calls:

```
 await callSendAPI(messageData);
```

And therefore the functions these calls are in need to be `async` too and `await`ed when called and so on.

Comment: i already tried this but still not working look at the edited code

Comment: @nikhil `await sendTextMessage(text);
await sendImageMessage(imgUrl);
await sendQuickReply(replies)`

Comment: to await callSendAPI, it should return a promise

Comment: @praveen it does. :/

Comment: I can't see any return there

Comment: i changed while calling function but no luck, a function that sends image it still sending last response

Comment: @JonasW. `await sendTextMessage(text); await sendImageMessage(imgUrl); await sendQuickReply(replies)` only valid, when second one need to execute after first one